# Bootstrap 3.2.0 Glyphicon disappears in Opera Browser Emulator?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Has anyone had problems that the glyphicon on Opera emulator browser not showing up? But shows up when you fire up your webpage?

Any ideas?

Form Webpage:

[image]

The opera mobile emulator:

[image]

Comment: [Custom fonts aren't supported on Opera mini 7](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface), assuming that's what you're using

Comment: Also, Bootstrap doesn't officially support Presto-based Opera in the first place.